# Idle timer in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I use this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

for autolock disabling. In Settings I set the lock time of 30 seconds. After some time the screen goes blank, and the device does not respond to touches and Home button pressing. Checked on iOS 9.2 (13C75), iPhone 5 ans 5s.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was occuring with me. Actually it does work but only works when your device is not connected to xCode. Try disconnecting the device and then test this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Try this funny hack.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

instead of

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but it don't work for me.